# Keyboard shortcuts for the Google Apps Script Programming Enviroment

Tags: google-apps-script, keyboard-shortcuts

If I push <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>up/down</kbd> I can move a line up or down, are there any others keyboard shortcuts for making faster the programming in the Google's enviroment?

Where can I see the list of keyboard shortcuts that I can use in the browser programming enviroment?

Can I add more?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the various pull-down menus in the editor.  You will see that <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> will complete a word.  Also, since the editor uses the same shortcuts, see the [Keyboard shortcuts for Google Docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/179738?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) list and expand for your particular system.

Comment: Thanks Karl, it's good to find it even if I can't change or add.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part of your question.  No, I have no known way to add more.  Unless things have changed recently you cannot even use Google Apps Script to add them to a spreadsheet or other doc.

Answer (score 0):

If you press `F1` (or right click -> Command Palette) you will see an autocomplete list of many commands and their shortcuts